# In multivariate maximization, is the max over $~(x, w)~$ of the objective $~f(x, w)~$ the same as the max of $~\frac{1}{x}f(x, w)~$?

Tags: derivatives, optimization, maxima-minima, constraints

Suppose $x = (x_1, x_2)$ or some longer real vector,  $q(x)$ is a concave function, and $~p_q,~ p_1 ~\text{and}~~ p_2~$ are real positive constants.

If $~x^*~$ is a unique solution to the optimization problem:

$$\max_{\text{over}~ x}   ~\left\{ p_q * q(x) - (p_1 * x_1 + p_2 * x_2)\right\}~,$$

is it also necessarily a solution to:

$$\max_{\text{over}~ x}  ~ \frac{1}{x_1} ~\left\{p_q * q(x) - (p_1 * x_1 + p_2 * x_2)\right\}~~?$$ 
 Alternatively, is it demonstrably not a solution (except perhaps in special cases)? If the latter, can we characterize the solution relative to $~x^*~$ (perhaps in terms of their respective first order conditions)?

Just for a motivating example, this is a modified version of the usual form of the producer's (i.e. the firm's) optimization problem. It is intended to capture the difference between competitive firms run by independent entrepreneurial executives -- that is the standard economic assumption -- and firms run by effectively-controlled agents of the stockholders. My thought is  that such agents would wish to maximise profits per unit of capital, rather than profits per se.  This feels to me like a minor extension of standard theory, but I keep getting nonsensical answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $q(x) = 1-x_2^2$ and $p_1 = p_2 = 0$ and $p_q = 1$, the maximum of the first problem is finite ($1$) while the second problem is unbounded (simply let $x_1$ tend to $0$ from above, so the answer is no.

Comment: This solution violates one of the stated  problem conditions, that all of the p constants are strictly positive. This is a modified version of a common economic optimization problem for the firm, so zero prices are unrealistic.

Comment: Ouch, missed that. However, your question is simply asking for a concave $q(x)$ and $p(x) = q(x) - (p_1x_1+p_2x_2)$ (you can skip $p_q$ ) such that there exist an 
 $x_2$ so that $p(x_1=0)>0$. Take for instance $p(x) = 10-x_1^2-x_2^2 - (x_1+x_2)$. Evaluate at $x_2 = 1$ and you have $8-x_1-x_1^2$. Divide by $x_1$ and let $x_1$ tend to 0 and you have infinity again.